# How to create custom sound events?

Tags: 12.04, unity, sound

Is it possible to create custom sound events in Unity? Like setting a raindrop sound to be triggered when the Dash is open, when you call the launcher, when your mouse hovers over icons in the launcher, when you open/close/minimize/maximize a folder, etc. If it is possible, then what is the easiest way to do it?